# ionic not generating android-build

Tags: ionic-framework, android-sdk-tools

[WARN] Not performing Ionic build for project type: ionic1.

> ionic cordova prepare android
>   cordova prepare android
>   Running command: "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" C:\Users\pini\Desktop\Drivercheckcall\hooks\after_prepare\010_add_platfo
>   rm_class.js C:\Users\pini\Desktop\Drivercheckcall

add to body class: platform-android
Running command: "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" C:\Users\pini\Desktop\Drivercheckcall\hooks\after_prepare\020_remove_sas
s_from_platforms.js C:\Users\pini\Desktop\Drivercheckcall

> cordova build android --release
>   × Running command - failed!
>   [ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova build android --release (exit code 1):

```
    Running command: "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe"
    C:\Users\pini\Desktop\Drivercheckcall\hooks\after_prepare\010_add_platform_class.js
    C:\Users\pini\Desktop\Drivercheckcall
    add to body class: platform-android
    Running command: "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe"
    C:\Users\pini\Desktop\Drivercheckcall\hooks\after_prepare\020_remove_sass_from_platforms.js
    C:\Users\pini\Desktop\Drivercheckcall
    ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\pini\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144
    Subproject Path: CordovaLib
    Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
    The Task.leftShift(Closure) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use
    Task.doLast(Action) instead.
            at build_yewq1sjt6kzw92w3qmfn4wt0.run(C:\Users\pini\Desktop\Drivercheckcall\platforms\android\build.gradle:1
```

39)

```
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * Where:
    Script
    'C:\Users\pini\Desktop\Drivercheckcall\platforms\android\phonegap-plugin-push\DriverCheckCall-push.gradle' line:
    38

    * What went wrong:
    A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
    > Failed to apply plugin [class 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin']
        > For input string: "+"

    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

    BUILD FAILED

    Total time: 23.062 secs
    Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * Where:
    Script
    'C:\Users\pini\Desktop\Drivercheckcall\platforms\android\phonegap-plugin-push\DriverCheckCall-push.gradle' line:
    38

    * What went wrong:
    A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
    > Failed to apply plugin [class 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin']
        > For input string: "+"

    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen this issue before with push plugin or maps plugin or google plugin, it's regarding cordova plugins and their dependencies, in your case this line it's helpful.

> Failed to apply plugin [class 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin']
>   For input string: "+"
>   :

So one fix will be: inside platforms/android open project.properties, you will have something like this

```
cordova.system.library.2=com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:+
cordova.system.library.3=com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:+
```

Try to have the google play services to match in version, in my case after specifying the version I ended up with the file like this:

```
# This file is automatically generated by Android Tools.
# Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!
#
# This file must be checked in Version Control Systems.
#
# To customize properties used by the Ant build system edit
# "ant.properties", and override values to adapt the script to your
# project structure.
#
# To enable ProGuard to shrink and obfuscate your code, uncomment this (available properties: sdk.dir, user.home):
#proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt
# Project target.
target=android-25
android.library.reference.1=CordovaLib
cordova.system.library.1=com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1+
cordova.system.library.2=com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.1
cordova.system.library.3=com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.1
cordova.system.library.4=com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.1
cordova.system.library.5=com.android.support:support-v13:25.1.0
cordova.system.library.6=me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.17@aar
cordova.system.library.7=com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.1
cordova.gradle.include.1=phonegap-plugin-push/custodian-push.gradle
cordova.system.library.8=com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3+
```

Comment: i am still getting same error


" inside platforms/android open project.properties"
# cordova.system.library.2=com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:+
cordova.system.library.2=com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:+
cordova.gradle.include.1=cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation/DriverCheckCall-logtofile.gradle
# cordova.system.library.3=com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:+
cordova.system.library.3=com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:+


i have done this changes

Comment: I see a lot of '+', you should have like what I showed you above in my response, replace the '+' with the actual version try the same I have for play services

Comment: I made changes to  com.google.gms:google-services:+ to  com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.2. Just put everything to the latest release version and it will work